# Disable confirmation when erasing & saving buffer

Tags: buffers

In the Emacs sources I found the following trick:

```el
(let (buffer-file-name)
  (erase-buffer))
```

which inhibits `ask-user-about-supersession-threat`, but I need to save the buffer too, so I can't hide `buffer-file-name`. So I decided to use function advice.

`basic-save-buffer` also asks:

```el
(yes-or-no-p
  (format
    "%s has changed since visited or saved.  Save anyway? "
    (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)))
```

which I want to avoid, so I ended up using the internal function `basic-save-buffer-1`:

```el
(defun my--erase-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (advice-add #'ask-user-about-supersession-threat :override #'identity)
  (erase-buffer)
  (when (buffer-file-name)
    (basic-save-buffer-1)
    (revert-buffer))
  (advice-remove #'ask-user-about-supersession-threat #'identity))
```

My motivation for this is that I need a key binding to clean up constantly updated log files during development.

This approach seems unnecessarily hackish. Is there place for improvement?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like that:

```
(defun ar-empty-buffer-and-save ()
  (interactive "*")
  (erase-buffer)
  (write-file (buffer-file-name))
  (ar-kill-buffer-unconditional))
```

with

```
(defun ar-kill-buffer-unconditional (&optional buffer)
  "Kill buffer unconditional, kill buffer-process if existing.

Sometimes being queried sucks..."
  (interactive
   (list (current-buffer)))
  (let ((buffer (or (and (bufferp buffer) buffer)
            (get-buffer (current-buffer))))
    proc kill-buffer-query-functions)
    (if (buffer-live-p buffer)
        (progn
          (setq proc (get-buffer-process buffer))
          (and proc (kill-process proc))
          (set-buffer buffer)
          (set-buffer-modified-p 'nil)
          (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
      (message "Can't see a buffer %s" buffer))))
```